# Undeleting a deleted answer doesn't refund the lost reputation before that answer was deleted

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-answers

Suppose your answer has a score of *0*, (*1* upvote and *1* downvote). Your reputation gain from the upvote is *+10*, and the reputation loss from the downvote is *-2*. So the net reputation gain from your answer is +8.

If you delete your answer, you will lose those *8* reputation points, but if  you then undelete it, you won't get back those *2* points.

I think this is a bug.

I don't know if this behavior is same for questions.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You will get the reputation delta back (unless there was no delta after the fact, e.g. the rep cap was later hit from some of those votes) **within 5 minutes**.  It's based on a task that runs every 5 minutes handling the rep sync for the delete/undelete case.

Comment: If the points don't come back in 5 minutes. then what can be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

If you have un-deleted the answer before a few minutes, wait for a while, it will be refunded automatically.

Or you can  trigger the reputation recalc from https://stackoverflow.com/reputation using <kbd>Trigger Reputation Recalc</kbd> button<sup>*</sup>. It recalc your reputation.

<sub>* Note: Reputation cannot be recalculated more than once per day.</sub>